# How exactly does dependency injection reduce coupling?

Tags: dependency-injection

I've done plenty of reading on Dependency Injection, but I have no idea, how does it actually reduce coupling?

The analogy I have of DI is that all components are registered with a container, so theyre are like in a treasure chest. To get a component, you obviously register it first, but then you would have to interrogate the treasure chest (which is like a layer of indirection). Is this the right analogy? It doesn't make obvious how the "injection" happens, though (how would that fit in with this analogy?).

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use an IoC Container framework to implement DI. A class with a constructor parameter of an interface type could be said to use constructor injection, even if the calling code simply passes a new instance of an implementing class. IoC Containers do help manage complexity.

Comment: DI doesn't *reduce* coupling. DI *enables* loose coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go with your analogy of your components being in a treasure chest:
A system (lets say a treasure polisher) without dependency injection has to have the ability to pick an item from the treasure chest itself. It has to have some knowledge the dependency's nature in order to pick the correct treasure to polish depending on the current context. Thus coupling.

In a DI scenario, your treasure polisher does not need to know about the existence of the treasure chest at all. All it needs to know is that at some point (preferably at creation) the polisher will be provided (injected) with an object which implements `ITreasure`:

```
interface ITreasure
{
    void PolishMe();
}
```

Thus your implementation class is de-coupled from your treasure chest.

Answer (score 70):

Dependency Injection (DI) doesn't *reduce coupling*, per se, because the component that relies on the dependency is still coupled to its dependency. What DI *does* accomplish, however, is to remove the responsibility of finding the dependency from the component itself, and placing that responsibility elsewhere.

A component that relies on DI is completely passive when it comes to its dependencies. There is no code in the component that says "create a new instance of this dependency" or "go out and get me this dependency". The dependency is *given* to (injected into) the component, usually when the component itself is created by some other object.

This reversal of responsibility to create (or ask for creation of) a dependency is called Inversion of Control (IoC).

So, if the component doesn't know how to create or ask for a dependency, where does that responsibility lie? Usually in an object created specifically for dependency resolution, commonly called an IoC container. In your analogy, this is your "treasure chest". The IoC container contains the instructions that basically say "when somebody asks for *this*, give them *one of these*. An IoC container can typically inspect the component it's asked to create, figure out what its dependencies are, and create them too, walking down the "dependency chain" until all of the dependencies are resolved.

The big shift in thinking, the injection, comes when deciding *who gets to ask the container for the component's dependency"? Without DI, it would be the component itself that would ask the container for its dependency. Using DI, however, the responsibility of asking the container to "resolve" a component's dependency falls to whatever *creates* or *uses* the component. When the component is created, whatever is creating it has the responsibility of providing all of the dependencies. The component doesn't know or care how they are created, just that they are.

Now, if the dependency is defined as a concrete implementation, the component is still *tightly coupled* to that specific concrete implementation, even though it is being injected. DI itself does not *reduce coupling* in that sense. But if the dependency is defined as an *interface*, the component doesn't care or know what the concrete implementation is, nor how it's created. It's still coupled to the dependency, but it is a very *loose coupling*.

In that sense, "Dependency Injection" and "Programming to Interfaces" combine to create very loosely coupled, highly flexible components.

Comment: finally a nice satisfactory answer on what actually dependency injection does. There is a lot of blubbering about 'reduced coupling' when it comes to DI, this one pinpoints what exactly is achieved by dependency injection. (although theoretically taking out the creation or finding logic from the class, does reduce the coupling)

Comment: @ralzaul Thanks for the nice comment. I find it funny that while you say "finally", when I look at this answer I think "wow, I wrote this almost 5 years ago". :-)

Comment: So perfectly answered ! I thought a lot about dependency injection and everywhere i found material saying as if loose coupling is a natural consequence of DI which i felt was so mythical concept yet people are carrying it in their minds like eternal truth. After all the analysis this is exactly what i felt and now i am going to put an article on this.

Comment: very helpful, especially this: "What DI does accomplish, however, is to remove the responsibility of finding the dependency from the component itself, and placing that responsibility elsewhere."

Comment: The coupling is 'loose' in the sense that it is possible to interchange the concrete implementation. But this is pointless complexity unless at some point such an ability to swap out concrete implementations is needed. DI is sometimes used very extensively for the purpose of being able to unit test in isolation from dependencies. Note that the additional DI required in this case is a cost and not an improvement of the architecture, as it would have otherwise served no purpose.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

The coupling is especially reduced if you use interfaces properly.

If the client only knows about the interface, now the possibilities open up.  You are freed to inject your own implementation or a proxied version; you can advise it with aspects without the client's knowledge; you can easily mock it during testing.  The client need not know the concrete type as it would if you simply called "new".

Comment: So DI is just another word for (Abstract) Factory? Also sounds very similar to the ASP.NET "provider" model. Is it truly different from these?

Comment: Abstract Factory is a good synonym.  I don't know about the provider model.

Comment: @StingyJack,dufftmo:Not really. In abstract factory you use a factory object to get a concrete implementation. With DI the concrete implementation is provided or "injected" at runtime. Client code does not create a factory to get an object. This responsibility has been delegated

Comment: I don't need correction in my understanding of DI.  "In abstract factory you use a factory object to get a concrete implementation" - that's exactly what dependency injection is doing.  The factory *is* created, and the client has to have a reference to it at startup to get an object implementation.  You've added nothing to the conversation with this comment.

Answer (score 2):

In DI one component calls another component only via a well-defined interface and all components "glue" together via configuration and not code.
As a result we can swap implementations used by an application by re-configuration alone.
As an example in containers you can visualize dependency-injection as a reversed look-up (if you have used JNDI).
Instead of having resource/module names hard-coded, you declare what is needed for a class (acting as a bean).The container is responsible for providing everything at run time.
This term was coined by Martin Fowler and you can check his article on the concept  [DI](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)